# nx run-commands target fails with MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: typescript, nomachine-nx

I have a working nx project with multiple apps and packages. I'm trying to add a script to one of the apps that I can execute directly from the CLI. I've added the below target to the app's project.json:

```
    "my-script": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "apps/my-app",
        "commands": ["ts-node src/my-script.ts"],
        "parallel": false
      }
    }
```

But it fails with a MODULE_NOT_FOUND when resolving imports from other packages. These imports work when I build the entire project itself. I'm using a tsconfig.base.json where I've added "paths" array entries for each of these other packages.

Is there some other way that I should be invoking my custom script within this project?

Comment: what happens when you run ts-node src/my-script.ts from apps/my-app in terminal?

Comment: Just tried that. Exact same error.

Comment: Seems to work after I added tsconfig-paths to the dependencies of the app's package.json, added the following snippet to the app's tsconfig.json, and did a yarn install within that folder:
  "ts-node": {"require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"] }